# OpenJPA Reverse Engineering - Can't get ReverseMappingTool to generate Entities properly

Tags: java, jpa, orm, reverse-engineering, openjpa

I place openjpa's ReverseMappingTool as a Mavin plugin in a desperate hope to generate entity classes that are at least as good as EclipseLink generated entity classes.

It generates the entity classes but no matter what options I choose, the entity classes have no Annotations (Yes I set -annotations to true for RMT).

There are other things that are going worse than this one, such as RMT generating an entity class for every id-attribute. But please chime in if you have ever worked with this tool.After  16 hours of trying to fix this problem, I'm now not sure if it's me who's gone crazy or is OpenJPA's ReverseMappingTool running on Vodka.

I started with this piece of POM I found in SO/some site.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.2</version>
<configuration>
<mainClass>org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool</mainClass>
<commandlineArgs>
    -directory src/main/java -accessType fields
    -useGenericCollections true -package org.herennow.model
    -metadata c -annotations true
    -innerIdentityClasses false -useBuiltinIdentityClass false
    -primaryKeyOnJoin true
    </commandlineArgs>
<includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
</configuration>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.CR3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
        <artifactId>openjpa-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please update your post with the properties that you are passing to the org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.meta.ReverseMappingTool.

Comment: @Rick. Please check above. So my minimal problems are 1. No annotations for mapping or anything else is getting generated. 2. Every id attribute has its own class.